# What's an optimal regex for to represent a binary 32-bit decimal number?

Tags: regex

Trying to fix Regex to match the following scenario:

- Up to 32 bit after decimal
- binary
- No leading or trailing zeros

> [0|1]*.?[0-1]+([0-1]{32})?

Regex should pass this: 1.001100101 but fail this: 1.0000000000000010

Comment: `\b1[01]*(?:\.[01]*1)?\b`? [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/h9p2yw/1).

Comment: What does "optimal regex" mean to you? Shortest, fastest, most maintainable?

Comment: @user135 Why should `1.0000000000000010` fail?  I think I am missing that part.  I don't play with binary often enough, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

From your description, this regex should do what you want:

```regex
^1[01]*(?:\.[01]{0,31}1)?$
```

It looks for a leading `1`, followed by some number of binary digits (`[01]`), and then an optional decimal part consisting of a decimal point (`\.`) followed by up to 31 binary digits (`[01]{0,31}`) and a trailing `1`.

[Demo on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/XY3Qq5/3)

If you're looking for the numbers inside a longer string, replace `^` and `$` with word breaks (`\b`).

**Update based on comments**

If you also want to match the values `0.0` and `1.0` (which do not meet the original criteria), you can add them as an alternation to the regex:

```regex
^(?:[01]\.0?|1[01]*(?:\.[01]{0,31}1)?)$
```

[Demo on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/sY2vCp/1)

Comment: @user13549955 I've updated my answer to also allow for matching 0.0 and 1.0

Answer (score -1):

The shortest (and simplest) regex I can think of to accomplish this is:

`^1\.[01]{0,31}?1$`

This requires a `1.` at the start, a `1` at the end, and also ensures a limit of 32 decimal places (including the final mandatory `1`).

And can be seen on Regex101 [here](https://regex101.com/r/DSRlxk/1/).

Comment: It seems like the OP is expecting one or more digits before the decimal place.

Comment: works partially,  is there a way to make it pass these conditions 0.0 and 1.0